# Изменить шрифт

Tags: android

Всем привет! Подскажите, как задать определённый шрифт всему приложению?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На сколько я знаю, варианта применить шрифт ко всему приложению нет.
Однако можно наследовать **TextView** и применить программно к нему шрифт, и во всем приложении использовать уже свой кастомный **TextView**

Пример кода вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376250/custom-fonts-and-xml-layouts-android/7197867#7197867)

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться вариантом, который предложил [[[[@falstaf](/users/5517/falstaf)](/users/5517/falstaf)](/users/5517/falstaf)](/users/5517/falstaf) но мне кажется, что в таком варианте есть один недостаток - нельзя задать свой шрифт, который лежит, например, в assets. Поэтому, я бы предложил завести базовую активити BaseActivity, в ней в onCreate() добавить код для нужных элементов(также нужно будет создавать базовый макет разметки):

```
view.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getResources().getAssets(), "superfont.ttf"));
```

И в дальнейшем все активити будут наследовать BaseActivity. Но это если вам нужно установить свой кастомный шрифт, а не его тип(жирный, подчеркнутый и т.д.), который можно поставить в варинте от [[[[@falstaf](/users/5517/falstaf)](/users/5517/falstaf)](/users/5517/falstaf)](/users/5517/falstaf)

Answer (score 2):

Опишите тему, назначьте её приложению в *AndroidManifest.xml*.
В стилях укажите нужное значение для *android:typeface*.
Более подробно - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#DefiningStyles

Comment: Да, но таким образом нельзя добавить свой шрифт из assets

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать как-то так для каждой активити, не знаю, есть ли способ проще.

```
    Typeface mFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/BPreplay.otf");
ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.myrootlayout);
setFont(root, mFont);

/*
 * Sets the font on all TextViews in the ViewGroup. Searches
 * recursively for all inner ViewGroups as well. Just add a
 * check for any other views you want to set as well (EditText,
 * etc.)
 */
public void setFont(ViewGroup group, Typeface font) {
    int count = group.getChildCount();
    View v;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        v = group.getChildAt(i);
        if(v instanceof TextView || v instanceof Button /*etc.*/)
            ((TextView)v).setTypeface(font);
        else if(v instanceof ViewGroup)
            setFont((ViewGroup)v, font);
    }
}
```

Comment: R.id.myrootlayout - где его взять

Answer (score 0):

Создайте отдельный класс:

```
class EasyFonts {

private EasyFonts(){}

static Typeface times_new_roman (Context context){
    return getFontFromRes(R.raw.times_new_roman, context);
}

private static Typeface getFontFromRes(int resource, Context context){
    Typeface sResTypeface;
    InputStream sInputStream = null;
    String sOutPath = context.getCacheDir() + "/tmp" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".raw";

    try {
        sInputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(resource);
    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException ignored){
    }

    try {
        assert sInputStream != null;
        byte[] sBuffer = new byte[sInputStream.available()];
        BufferedOutputStream sBOutStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(sOutPath));
        int l = 0;
        while ((l = sInputStream.read(sBuffer)) > 0){
            sBOutStream.write(sBuffer, 0, l);
        }
        sBOutStream.close();

        sResTypeface = Typeface.createFromFile(sOutPath);

        new File(sOutPath).delete();
    } catch (IOException e){
        return null;
    }
    return sResTypeface;
   }
}
```

Затем создайте директорию `raw` на уровне `res`, поместите нужные вам шрифты в `raw`, название шрифтов должно быть строчными буквами формата `.ttf` и затем задавайте шрифт программно.

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
// Во фрагментах
text.setTypeface(EasyFonts.times_new_roman(getActivity()));
// В активити
text.setTypeface(EasyFonts.times_new_roman(this));
```