# Применение шрифтов лучшим образом

Tags: java, android, шрифты

Каким образом применять нужные шрифты ко всей программе, есть ли какой-то один метод, который считается лучшим среди программистов?

Comment: я тоже хочу знать это заветное слово

Comment: Слово причем? Я спрашиваю о методе. У меня в программе в некоторых местах через `xml` разметку в `fontFamily` задан шрифт, где то через отдельный класс посредством которого я задаю `view.setTypeface()`. Я хочу знать, какой вообще из методов задавать шрифты считается лучшим среди опытных программистов.

Comment: в теме приложения прописываете fontFamily

Comment: @SviatVolkov наверное ваш вариант самый оптимальный, можете вывести в ответ, отмечу

Answer (score 3):

Не уверен в том, что этот способ самый лучший. Но для меня самый удобный.

Сперва инициализирую шрифты в `MyApplication`:

```
private static Typeface robotoRegular;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    robotoRegular = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");

}

public static Typeface getRobotoRegular() {
    return robotoRegular;
}
```

Создаю кастомный класс:

```
public class TextViewRegular extends AppCompatTextView {

        public TextViewRegular(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            setTypeface(context);
        }

        public TextViewRegular(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            setTypeface(context);
        }

        public TextViewRegular(Context context) {
            super(context);
            setTypeface(context);
        }
        private void setTypeface(Context context) {
            if (context != null & !isInEditMode()) {
                setTypeface(MyApplication.getRobotoRegular(), Typeface.NORMAL);
            }
        }
}
```

И использую везде:

```
<com.devoma.project.ui.widget.TextViewRegular
android:id="@+id/lastMessageTime"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

И самое главное не забыть в `manifest` прописать имя `application`, то есть:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
```

Comment: У меня есть метод, с в отдельном классе, но там только программно задается шрифт. в этом ответе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/189757/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%88%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%82/660596#660596 там же в отмеченном ответе тоже есть другой метод, похожий на ваш, поэтому стало интересно, каким же методом пользуются опытные